# Axios post on buttonClick, to later render this data on same page

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to do a page on which i could rate a book (now just by button click).

```
const ratingHandler = () => {
    axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}/rate`, { score: 5 });
  };


 <button onClick={ratingHandler}>Rate</button>
```

This code works well, i can se in my database that the new rating is pushed.
But later on, on the same page i want to render this data.
For this I am using:

```
<p>
   Rate: {about.rating_count} / {about.rating_sum}
</p>
```

And of course im getting the data once again:

```
 const [about, aboutWhat] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}`)
      .then((response) => aboutWhat(response.data));
  });
```

Rating count = How many times u pressed the button.
Rating Sum = Summing the rates.
These two works fine. But i cannot render this Rate using the code above. Anyone have an idea how can i render this data?

```
import Card from "../ui/Card";
import classes from "./MeetupItem.module.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const axios = require("axios");
const HighlightedQuote = (props) => {
  const [about, aboutWhat] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}`)
      .then((response) => aboutWhat(response.data));
  });
  const removeHanlder = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    });
  };
  const ratingHandler = () => {
    axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}/rate`, { score: 5 });
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.item}>
      <Card>
        <div className={classes.image}>
          <img src={props.image_url} alt={props.title} />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.content}>
          <p>
            Rate: {about.rating_count} / {about.rating_sum}
          </p>
          <button onClick={ratingHandler}>Rate</button>
        </div>
        <button onClick={removeHanlder}>Delete</button>
        <Link to={`/edit-book/${props.id}`}>
          <button>Edit</button>
        </Link>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};
export default HighlightedQuote;
```

Comment: Try this: `aboutWhat([...response.data])`

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): response.data is not iterable

Comment: What you get in response.data is it an array or object?

Comment: And is your useEffect get called after you click `ratingHandler`?

Comment: Object.. :   {id: 103, title: "Harry Potter", author: "J.K Rowling ", genre: "Fantasy", release_date: "2001-06-29T22:00:00.000Z", …}

Comment: Then change it to `aboutWhat({...response.data})`

Comment: No it's not called after the click. I don't really know how to get data after the click :/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate function for getting book data and then call it whenever you need.

**Explanation**:

> 1. Created `getBookData` method
> 2. Calling it inside `useEffect` and in `ratingHandler`

### Solution:

```
 const [about, aboutWhat] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    getBookData();
  }, []);

  const getBookData = () => {
   axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}`)
      .then((response) => aboutWhat({...response.data}));
  }

 const ratingHandler = async () => {
    await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}/rate`, { score: 5 });
   getBookData();
  };
```

Comment: Well it works fine, when I am looking at database. Although the  `<p>
            Rate: {about.rating_count} / {about.rating_sum}
          </p>`  is still not rendered on the page.

Comment: Have you inspected the response payload? It should be like `{ rating_count: 3, rating_sum: 5 }`;

Comment: @sheeshwarrior Have you done like this: `aboutWhat({...response.data}))` ?

Comment: To debug, you could replace the implementation of getBookData by: `const getBookData = () => { aboutWhat({ rating_count: Math.round(Math.random() * 5), rating_sum: 5 }); };`

Comment: @JonathanWeibel If i replace getBookData like you said, the rating is being rendered. But how can i implement it so it would work by taking data from database, not using math.random

Comment: I would first inspect the HTTP response in devtools network tab to check the format of the JSON. Then adapt the backend endpoint or the client.

Answer (score 1):

Your UI is not aware that you have made some changes in the `rating` and also since you have your `fetch` in the useEffect it will not run unless there is a re-render in your component. So you need to explicitly cause a re-render in your component for your useEffect to run or you can fire the `fetch` call once your post is done.

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
       const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}`);
       aboutWhat(data)
    }catch(error){
       // do something with error
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      fetchData();
  }, []);

  const ratingHandler = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}/rate`, {score: 5});
      if(response is successful){
          // refetch the data
          fetchData();
      }
    }catch(error){
      .... 
    } 
  };
```

Comment: I think an `await` is missing before `axios.post` and also `about` is an Object and not an Array, so declare it like that: `const [about, aboutWhat] = useState({});`